# How to modify "People search results template" in SharePoint 2013 in the general search

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-search, sharepoint-userprofile

I want to know how to modify the "People search results template" section in the general search. When I wrote a name in the general search, there is always a section in the top of the search result that shows : Preferred Name, JobTile, Department. I want to modify this template to add more User Profil Property just like I did in Item_Person.html in a standard people search webpart, but I can't find the correct template.

I don't need to know how to modify it, i just need to know where is the file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,
Find which display template that you use for search result. You can find this by following

Site Settings -> Search Result Types (rootsite/_layouts/15/manageresulttypes.aspx?level=sitecol).
In the "Defined for this site collection title" find the template that you use for people result.
then edit it. In the edit screen, you will find the path of display template at the bottom.

Then, 
Open Sharepoint designer find the template and edit it.

I hope this will solve your problem.